# How to expand out the application hamburger menu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, menu-bar, globalmenu

[image: screenshot of konsole title bar]

I want to turn the hamburger menu in the title bar into something similar to the global menu.

The global menu is great but I can't go to the corner to close the app anymore. I have to waste extra seconds to look at the corner and move the mouse down a bit.

Also, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> does nothing in any app I tried it on.

When I have both the global menu and the hamburger menu, pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>char</kbd> opens the corresponding tab in both menus.

It would be a great feature if it turned back into hamburger menu if there was not enough space to show all menu options.

Comment: I dont want a different panel for the expanded menu bar. i want it in my window decoration (where the close maximize minimize buttons are)

Comment: or to move the close minimize maximize (and keep above) buttons up to window that panel somehow and get rid of window decorations. that should work too.

Comment: do you know of a way to embed the global menu widget into the window decoration? I only managed to do it to the panel which I put on top.

Answer (score 1):

The name of what you're looking for is "locally integrated menus" for "window decorations". This is not currently possible natively in KDE.

There is however the extension [Material Decorations](https://github.com/Zren/material-decoration) by Zren.

There is also an [open merge request](https://invent.kde.org/plasma/breeze/-/merge_requests/126) to support this in the native Breeze decorations.

As far as I see though this will permanently put the menu entries in the title bar, not toggle them on hamburger button press.

Comment: thank you for looking for this. seems to be a work in progress. I will keep an eye on it.